# Default values on claims on built in signup/login poliices Azure B2C

Tags: azure, token, jwt, azure-ad-b2c, claims

I am using a SIGN-UP OR SIGN-IN POLICY on Azure B2C. I added two custom attributes to be used as application claims.

I want to set a default value to one of those attributes when a user is created.

I found that I can use custom policies; maybe there is a way to modify the existent policies to add that behavior?

Comment: Is the value the same for all users or needs to be determined somehow?

Comment: Hi! Is the same value for all users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I found that I can use custom policies; maybe there is a way to modify
>   the existent policies to add that behavior?

You can provide the default value for a claim that will be added to all users in custom policies. However, this feature is not yet available on standard policies (I assume that's what you meant by "existent" policies?)

In custom policies, this can be achieved by doing something similar to the following in the AAD profile:

```
<InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" DefaultValue="none" />
```

Every time a user is created, the displayName will be set to "none".